# Draw tree diagram in gwt

Tags: gwt

I want to draw tree diagram in gwt with custom connector color . Is it possible using some jar in gwt. I want to show hierarchy with diffrent connector color.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use google visualization libraries. The [org chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart) might be useful in your case. This is a javascript library that's been adapted to GWT so don't worry if you find JS code in the documentation.

Take a look at the documentation and make sure that this is what you're looking for then download the visualization libraries for GWT from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgwtvisualizationjar.htm).

Comment: but how to change the connector color between child and parent node?

Comment: I think this functionality has not been implemented yet. There's an issue for it though here: https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/871

Answer (score 0):

I would say to look into a wrapper for Raphaël.
But currently the Raphaël website is down so I am not sure about the state of this product. Although in Github I see a commit from only 5 days ago.